# Flutter: How to install Flutter and its required SDK elements in Apple M1 Chip?

Tags: java, android, ios, xcode, flutter

I purchased a new Apple MacBook Pro, M1 Chip laptop. Mainly for Flutter programming, for both Android and iOS. After installing `OpenJDK`, I realised it is not supported in M1 chip because it was for Intel chip. So had to shift to `Azul OpenJDK`.

More browsing showed me that a proper Android emulator is not there yet, Google Maps does not work on iOS simulator yet, and so on. Instead of looking solutions for issues SDK by SDK or Tool by Tool, it is best to have a proper guide to setup the `Flutter` development base in M1.

Can someone list down the step by step instructions for setting up `Flutter` base in Apple M1 Chip, which includes `Java`, `Android Studio`, `Flutter` and `XCode`?

Answer (score 4):

I own M1 chip for at least 2 months. I have no issues with flutter (but notice it works with Rosetta2). I don't know what you're doing wrong but I just installed the last stable version (2.2.3) from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) and have no problems.

Also [Dart SDK beta](https://isapplesiliconready.com/app/Dart%20SDK) is compatible with M1 chip. But need to check if any flutter beta is working with it.

And [Android Studio stable](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) is compatible with M1 chip, but please make sure you download (64-bit, ARM) option. Embedded in android studio emulator is ready for M1 and it works well for API 30+.

So... I can confirm that there are no more issues with flutter on M1 than on intel's machine. And I'm a bit confused about your question because it was an easy installation.

Answer (score 3):

I also purchased the Macbook M1. I face many errors but the major/biggest of them is to isntall separate android emulator.
Here you can find it.
https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases

remaining JAVA, FLUTTER SDK are same but in installing and running the project on xcode you might face some problem in installing the Coca-PODs.

Comment: You installed Oracle JDK? What are the issues you faced abs how did tot fix them? The Android emulator, you donr have to install it via github. Now you can get it directly from Android studio

Comment: yes i choose the macOS installer from this list  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html

Comment: It is using Rosetta. Plus, it has license matters, that's why we are on OpenJDK

Comment: Let us know the cocopod experience. I think now XCode auto figures out.

Comment: yes, i also remember the now the coca-pods are not installing using the terminal. so i enable the resetta on the current terminal and then it install the coca-pods. but I am not sure i face this in installing coca-pods or somewhere else.

Comment: You have to install Rosetta separately or it comes by default? Also any experience with Google maps on both Android and iOS using M1 ?

Comment: it come with default setting. drag and drop the terminal on desktop and then right click and then GET INFO and the enable it for that current terminal only 
https://paste.pics/6bb2199b6e03182a73326f508265369a

Comment: In an answer below, another member says he faced lot of issues in installing the flutter SDK. same for you too?

Comment: no I dont think. the only problem that the users face in flutter SDK is to export the path.

Comment: what's up with that? Flutter path set do not change from processor to processor isn't it? It is the same for Apple macs

Comment: yes, this is not based on processor. I have faced no issue in installing the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

M1 owner here.
I can't even install a flutter path and flutter onto the machine. Brew installations, various youtube tutorials, official flutter tutorials/githubs ain't helping.

m1 and flutter are very messed up currently just 'starting' is impossible for some people (hundreds of comments on youtube).

currently lost what to do. Perhaps sell m1 for an older machine that actually can run flutter.

Update: made a tutorial how to set up flutter on m1 chip
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWB4htZWDTg&t=18s

Comment: WOW, that is crazy! I hear lot of good news about M1 flutter install, this is the first time I heard the other way around.

Comment: It's not all rainbow and sunshine.
I'm sure it's doable but it's not straightforward.

Comment: Made a tutorial for flutter m1 setting it up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWB4htZWDTg&t=18s

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SDK for M1, M2, M3 Chip (Apple Silicon)

- Download SDK file through
  https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/mobile-ios?tab=download
- Unzip your flutter sdk files and copy entire files.
- Go to "Go" $Home -> create a folder like  ~/development/
- Paste all files inside of "development" folder.

Open Terminal

1. Enter ~ls -al
2. Check the file name like ".zshrc" or ".zshenv"
3. If not, Create any one like "touch .zshenv"
4. It has created now enter "open .zshenv"
5. Text editor will open and paste following command "export PATH=$HOME/development/flutter/bin:$PATH
   "
6. Command + S save this file and close text editor , terminal.
7. Reopen Terminal and check command "flutter doctor"
8. You will see this[image]

9. If any files is missing in flutter doctor to install those tools.